Pivot Table - Display empty rows
There are time pivot tables do not have a full set of data. As a result Microsoft ignores those rows. The example below doesn't display the rows 1,2,3.
I would like to have it display a "0" (or anything really) as shown in the picture to the right.



A pivot table wouldn't know what's missing. You'll probably need to construct a table that is like the pivot table.

yeah :(  I was hoping somebody had figured things out. All I can think of is adding to the raw data ... but that creates it's own set of issues

@Mayo  ,,,,There is no reason that the PT is ignoring the Rows 1 , 2, 3 with ZEROs ,,,,  PT has not ant such default setting that ignore or exclude Row has ZERo ,,, better share the original WB if possible,,,, and if the left most screen shot is the source data then how would you expect Row 1 to 3 with ZEROs !!

@RajeshSinha - I was grasping at straws - that there might have been a way to display 0,1,2,3 ... 8,910 even if data was missing. I solve this in a variety of way (vlookups) and sometimes adding data. (I would add rows, but those are really kludgy solutions.) Again I was grasping at straws and hoping that someone had a better workaround.
